# how to show calender horizontally

Tags: android, calendar

please cann any one help me. i post many time no one help me my problemis very simple this is sample code http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/10/custom-calendar-in-android.html#comment-form

its show calender in gridview  but my requirement is show current week of dates only when user clik on button show next week of dates see below

```
       21 is current date of month

    Sun  Mon tues  Wed  Thurs  Fri  Sat
    18    19   20  (21)  22    23    24

      when clickon nextweewk button     show dates like that 

           Sun  Mon tues  Wed  Thurs  Fri  Sat
           25   26   27   28   29     30    31


   below is complete source code






                    @TargetApi(3)
  public class MyCalendarActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
  private static final String tag = "MyCalendarActivity";

 private TextView currentMonth;
 private Button selectedDayMonthYearButton;
 private ImageView prevMonth;
 private ImageView nextMonth;
 private GridView calendarView;
 private GridCellAdapter adapter;
 private Calendar _calendar;
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
 private int month, year;
   @SuppressWarnings("unused")
 @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi" })
 private final DateFormat dateFormatter = new DateFormat();
 private static final String dateTemplate = "MMMM yyyy";

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.my_calendar_view);

 _calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
 month = _calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
 year = _calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
 Log.d(tag, "Calendar Instance:= " + "Month: " + month + " " + "Year: "
+ year);

 selectedDayMonthYearButton = (Button) this
 .findViewById(R.id.selectedDayMonthYear);
 selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText("Selected: ");

  prevMonth = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.prevMonth);
  prevMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

 currentMonth = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.currentMonth);
  currentMonth.setText(DateFormat.format(dateTemplate,
  _calendar.getTime()));

  nextMonth = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.nextMonth);
  nextMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

  calendarView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.calendar);

  // Initialised
    adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
     R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

  /**
 * 
  * @param month
 * @param year
 */
 private void setGridCellAdapterToDate(int month, int year) {
 adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
  R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
 _calendar.set(year, month - 1, _calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
  currentMonth.setText(DateFormat.format(dateTemplate,
 _calendar.getTime()));
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
  }

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  if (v == prevMonth) {
 if (month <= 1) {
 month = 12;
 year--;
 } else {
  month--;
 }
 Log.d(tag, "Setting Prev Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: "
 + month + " Year: " + year);
 setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
 }
 if (v == nextMonth) {
 if (month > 11) {
  month = 1;
  year++;
 } else {
 month++;
 }
 Log.d(tag, "Setting Next Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: "
 + month + " Year: " + year);
  setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
 }

 }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
  Log.d(tag, "Destroying View ...");
    super.onDestroy();
  }

  // Inner Class
  public class GridCellAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {
  private static final String tag = "GridCellAdapter";
  private final Context _context;

   private final List<String> list;
  private static final int DAY_OFFSET = 1;
    private final String[] weekdays = new String[] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue",
  "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };
    private final String[] months = { "January", "February", "March",
 "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
 "October", "November", "December" };
  private final int[] daysOfMonth = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30,
 31, 30, 31 };
 private int daysInMonth;
 private int currentDayOfMonth;
  private int currentWeekDay;
 private Button gridcell;
 private TextView num_events_per_day;
 private final HashMap<String, Integer> eventsPerMonthMap;
 private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
 "dd-MMM-yyyy");

 // Days in Current Month
  public GridCellAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
 int month, int year) {
 super();
  this._context = context;
 this.list = new ArrayList<String>();
 Log.d(tag, "==> Passed in Date FOR Month: " + month + " "
  + "Year: " + year);
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  setCurrentDayOfMonth(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
 setCurrentWeekDay(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
 Log.d(tag, "New Calendar:= " + calendar.getTime().toString());
  Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfWeek :" + getCurrentWeekDay());
 Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfMonth :" + getCurrentDayOfMonth());

 // Print Month
 printMonth(month, year);

   // Find Number of Events
  eventsPerMonthMap = findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(year, month);
 }

  private String getMonthAsString(int i) {
 return months[i];
 }

 private String getWeekDayAsString(int i) {
  return weekdays[i];
 }

  private int getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(int i) {
 return daysOfMonth[i];
}

 public String getItem(int position) {
 return list.get(position);
 }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
  return list.size();
 }

 /**
 * Prints Month
 * 
 * @param mm
 * @param yy
 */
 private void printMonth(int mm, int yy) {
 Log.d(tag, "==> printMonth: mm: " + mm + " " + "yy: " + yy);
 int trailingSpaces = 0;
 int daysInPrevMonth = 0;
 int prevMonth = 0;
 int prevYear = 0;
 int nextMonth = 0;
 int nextYear = 0;

 int currentMonth = mm - 1;
 String currentMonthName = getMonthAsString(currentMonth);
 daysInMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(currentMonth);

  Log.d(tag, "Current Month: " + " " + currentMonthName + " having "
  + daysInMonth + " days.");

  GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(yy, currentMonth, 1);
  Log.d(tag, "Gregorian Calendar:= " + cal.getTime().toString());

  if (currentMonth == 11) {
   prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
  daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
  nextMonth = 0;
  prevYear = yy;
  nextYear = yy + 1;
  Log.d(tag, "*->PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
  + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
  + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
  } else if (currentMonth == 0) {
  prevMonth = 11;
  prevYear = yy - 1;
  nextYear = yy;
  daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
  nextMonth = 1;
  Log.d(tag, "**--> PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
  + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
  + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
   } else {
  prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
  nextMonth = currentMonth + 1;
  nextYear = yy;
  prevYear = yy;
  daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
  Log.d(tag, "***---> PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
  + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
  + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
  }

 int currentWeekDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
 trailingSpaces = currentWeekDay;

  Log.d(tag, "Week Day:" + currentWeekDay + " is "
  + getWeekDayAsString(currentWeekDay));
  Log.d(tag, "No. Trailing space to Add: " + trailingSpaces);
 Log.d(tag, "No. of Days in Previous Month: " + daysInPrevMonth);

 if (cal.isLeapYear(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)))
 if (mm == 2)
  ++daysInMonth;
  else if (mm == 3)
 ++daysInPrevMonth;

  // Trailing Month days
  for (int i = 0; i < trailingSpaces; i++) {
  Log.d(tag,
  "PREV MONTH:= "
    + prevMonth
    + " => "
    + getMonthAsString(prevMonth)
    + " "
    + String.valueOf((daysInPrevMonth
      - trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET)
      + i));
  list.add(String
   .valueOf((daysInPrevMonth - trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET)
    + i)
   + "-GREY"
   + "-"
  + getMonthAsString(prevMonth)
  + "-"
  + prevYear);
 }

 // Current Month Days
 for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
  Log.d(currentMonthName, String.valueOf(i) + " "
  + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + " " + yy);
  if (i == getCurrentDayOfMonth()) {
  list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-BLUE" + "-"
   + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
  } else {
  list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-"
   + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
  }
 }

 // Leading Month days
 for (int i = 0; i < list.size() % 7; i++) {
  Log.d(tag, "NEXT MONTH:= " + getMonthAsString(nextMonth));
  list.add(String.valueOf(i + 1) + "-GREY" + "-"
  + getMonthAsString(nextMonth) + "-" + nextYear);
 }
 }

 /**
 * NOTE: YOU NEED TO IMPLEMENT THIS PART Given the YEAR, MONTH, retrieve
 * ALL entries from a SQLite database for that month. Iterate over the
 * List of All entries, and get the dateCreated, which is converted into
 * day.
 * 
 * @param year
  * @param month
 * @return
 */
 private HashMap<String, Integer> findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(int year,
  int month) {
 HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

 return map;
}

@Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
 return position;
}

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 View row = convertView;
 if (row == null) {
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context
  .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_gridcell, parent, false);
 }

 // Get a reference to the Day gridcell
  gridcell = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.calendar_day_gridcell);
  gridcell.setOnClickListener(this);

  // ACCOUNT FOR SPACING

  Log.d(tag, "Current Day: " + getCurrentDayOfMonth());
  String[] day_color = list.get(position).split("-");
   String theday = day_color[0];
  String themonth = day_color[2];
   String theyear = day_color[3];
   if ((!eventsPerMonthMap.isEmpty()) && (eventsPerMonthMap != null)) {
  if (eventsPerMonthMap.containsKey(theday)) {
  num_events_per_day = (TextView) row
    .findViewById(R.id.num_events_per_day);
   Integer numEvents = (Integer) eventsPerMonthMap.get(theday);
  num_events_per_day.setText(numEvents.toString());
  }
 }

 // Set the Day GridCell
 gridcell.setText(theday);
 gridcell.setTag(theday + "-" + themonth + "-" + theyear);
 Log.d(tag, "Setting GridCell " + theday + "-" + themonth + "-"
  + theyear);

  if (day_color[1].equals("GREY")) {
  gridcell.setTextColor(getResources()
   .getColor(R.color.lightgray));
 }
  if (day_color[1].equals("WHITE")) {
 gridcell.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
   R.color.lightgray02));
}
if (day_color[1].equals("BLUE")) {
 gridcell.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orrange));
 }
 return row;
}

 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
 String date_month_year = (String) view.getTag();
 selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText("Selected: " + date_month_year);
 Log.e("Selected date", date_month_year);
 try {
  Date parsedDate = dateFormatter.parse(date_month_year);
  Log.d(tag, "Parsed Date: " + parsedDate.toString());

 } catch (ParseException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
 }

 public int getCurrentDayOfMonth() {
 return currentDayOfMonth;
}

 private void setCurrentDayOfMonth(int currentDayOfMonth) {
 this.currentDayOfMonth = currentDayOfMonth;
}

 public void setCurrentWeekDay(int currentWeekDay) {
 this.currentWeekDay = currentWeekDay;
 }

public int getCurrentWeekDay() {
return currentWeekDay;
}
}
}
```

Comment: use a horizontal layout in your XML  android:orientation="horizontal"

Comment: is not help me bcoz i want to show nextweek of dates when click how i will do that? also when screen start show current week of dates

Comment: on your xml file use android:orientation="horizontal" on your layout show me your layout/xml file

Comment: i want to doo like this way http://imgur.com/vWDuUPt

Comment: when user click on nextweek button show dates of nextweek

Comment: full source code is here  http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/10/custom-calendar-in-android.html#comment-form  just tell me how i onnly show current week of dates? and also show next week and previous week of dates when click on farward and back arrow button

Comment: satine do u give e ur email addresss

Comment: wait il see it im still downloading it is this all your code?

Comment: nois example code i m making application which display calender this way http://imgur.com/aBXY0NU show only current wek of dates when user click farward arrow show next week of dates and when clickon back arrow show previoous week of dates

Comment: satine do u give me your email address????

Comment: just ask here and i will try to help you

Comment: i not getting my prblem example code which url i sent u show dates in gridview from 1 to 31 all month i just want to print only current week of dates and 2 button when click 1 button its will show next week of dates in gridview when click onbutton 2 it wil show previous week of dates in gridview

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60sp"
    android:background="@drawable/topbar"
    android:gravity="left|top"
    android:height="60sp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="54sp"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:background="@drawable/meenu" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/prevMonth"
        android:layout_width="20sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
        android:src="@drawable/calendar_left_arrow_selector" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/currentMonth"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nextMonth"
        android:layout_width="20sp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
        android:src="@drawable/calendar_right_arrow_selector" >
    </ImageView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addEvent"
        android:layout_width="54sp"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:background="@drawable/plus" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/selectedDayMonthYear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/calendar_top_header"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
</Button>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/calendarheader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/calendar_days" >
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/calendar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="7" >
</GridView>
```

Comment: nothing will happen problem is not in xml is on coding sample example code show dates from 1 to 31 i want to display only  current wek of dates do u give me ur email address? cani sent u code>??

Comment: thnxx wait i m   sending

Comment: i mailed u from hotmail id

Comment: i sent u  now check please i sent u check ur junk or spam filter

Comment: this gut help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766665/how-to-get-current-week-days-in-calender but his code not show correct date when i set my phone to 1 august2013

Comment: check my mail satine pkease

Comment: i just checked it what you want is when i click on the arrow the next week of the same month will appear?you should make a button to display the next button or make a layout that displays the whole week the month.can you please again what do you want to make so i can try and make a solution for you

Comment: i want to to code on this button which is on xml   <Button
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="54sp"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:background="@drawable/meenu" />

Comment: when user click this button it will display next week of dates on screen