# how to show only current week of dates?

Tags: android, date, calendar

how to show onlyc urrent week of dates? this code below is print in gridview how to filter this to show only curent week of dates????  i want to show only current week of dates in below code  is show all datesin gridview form 1to 31 i want to show only current wek of dates

```
      Sun Mon Tues  Wednes Thurs  Fri  sat
      21  22   23    24     25    26   27


                  // Current Month Days
 for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
 Log.d(currentMonthName, String.valueOf(i) + " "
 + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + " " + yy);
 if (i == getCurrentDayOfMonth()) {
list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-BLUE" + "-"
+ getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
} else {
list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-"
+ getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
}
}

     ///    bellow is full source code  /////////
 @TargetApi(3)
   public class MyCalendarActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
   private static final String tag = "MyCalendarActivity";

 private TextView currentMonth;
 private Button selectedDayMonthYearButton;
 private ImageView prevMonth;
 private ImageView nextMonth;
 private GridView calendarView;
 private GridCellAdapter adapter;
  private Calendar _calendar;
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
 private int month, year;
 @SuppressWarnings("unused")
 @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi" })
 private final DateFormat dateFormatter = new DateFormat();
 private static final String dateTemplate = "MMMM yyyy";

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.my_calendar_view);

  _calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
  month = _calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
   year = _calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
  Log.d(tag, "Calendar Instance:= " + "Month: " + month + " " + "Year: "
  + year);

  selectedDayMonthYearButton = (Button) this
 .findViewById(R.id.selectedDayMonthYear);
  selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText("Selected: ");

    prevMonth = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.prevMonth);
    prevMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

    currentMonth = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.currentMonth);
    currentMonth.setText(DateFormat.format(dateTemplate,
      _calendar.getTime()));

    nextMonth = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.nextMonth);
    nextMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

  calendarView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.calendar);

  // Initialised
  adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
  R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
  }

 /**
 * 
 * @param month
 * @param year
 */
private void setGridCellAdapterToDate(int month, int year) {
adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
 R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
_calendar.set(year, month - 1, _calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
  currentMonth.setText(DateFormat.format(dateTemplate,
 _calendar.getTime()));
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

  @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 if (v == prevMonth) {
 if (month <= 1) {
   month = 12;
   year--;
  } else {
   month--;
 }
  Log.d(tag, "Setting Prev Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: "
   + month + " Year: " + year);
 setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
  }
 if (v == nextMonth) {
 if (month > 11) {
    month = 1;
  year++;
 } else {
   month++;
  }
  Log.d(tag, "Setting Next Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: "
 + month + " Year: " + year);
 setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
 }

  }

 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
 Log.d(tag, "Destroying View ...");
 super.onDestroy();
 }

 // Inner Class
  public class GridCellAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {
  private static final String tag = "GridCellAdapter";
  private final Context _context;

 private final List<String> list;
 private static final int DAY_OFFSET = 1;
 private final String[] weekdays = new String[] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue",
 "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };
 private final String[] months = { "January", "February", "March",
"April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
"October", "November", "December" };
 private final int[] daysOfMonth = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30,
 31, 30, 31 };
 private int daysInMonth;
 private int currentDayOfMonth;
 private int currentWeekDay;
  private Button gridcell;
  private TextView num_events_per_day;
  private final HashMap<String, Integer> eventsPerMonthMap;
  private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
  "dd-MMM-yyyy");

  // Days in Current Month
   public GridCellAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
  int month, int year) {
   super();
  this._context = context;
 this.list = new ArrayList<String>();
  Log.d(tag, "==> Passed in Date FOR Month: " + month + " "
 + "Year: " + year);
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   setCurrentDayOfMonth(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
   setCurrentWeekDay(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
   Log.d(tag, "New Calendar:= " + calendar.getTime().toString());
   Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfWeek :" + getCurrentWeekDay());
   Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfMonth :" + getCurrentDayOfMonth());

  // Print Month
  printMonth(month, year);

 // Find Number of Events
  eventsPerMonthMap = findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(year, month);
  }

 private String getMonthAsString(int i) {
  return months[i];
 }

  private String getWeekDayAsString(int i) {
  return weekdays[i];
 }

 private int getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(int i) {
 return daysOfMonth[i];
}

 public String getItem(int position) {
 return list.get(position);
 }

   @Override
  public int getCount() {
  return list.size();
 }

 /**
* Prints Month
* 
* @param mm
 * @param yy
 */
  private void printMonth(int mm, int yy) {
  Log.d(tag, "==> printMonth: mm: " + mm + " " + "yy: " + yy);
 int trailingSpaces = 0;
 int daysInPrevMonth = 0;
 int prevMonth = 0;
 int prevYear = 0;
 int nextMonth = 0;
 int nextYear = 0;

 int currentMonth = mm - 1;
 String currentMonthName = getMonthAsString(currentMonth);
 daysInMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(currentMonth);

Log.d(tag, "Current Month: " + " " + currentMonthName + " having "
 + daysInMonth + " days.");

 GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(yy, currentMonth, 1);
Log.d(tag, "Gregorian Calendar:= " + cal.getTime().toString());

 if (currentMonth == 11) {
 prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
  daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
 nextMonth = 0;
 prevYear = yy;
 nextYear = yy + 1;
 Log.d(tag, "*->PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
  + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
   + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
 else if (currentMonth == 0) {
  prevMonth = 11;
 prevYear = yy - 1;
 nextYear = yy;
 daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
 nextMonth = 1;
 Log.d(tag, "**--> PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
  + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
  + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
  } else {
  prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
   nextMonth = currentMonth + 1;
  nextYear = yy;
 prevYear = yy;
  daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
  Log.d(tag, "***---> PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
   + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
  + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
 }

 int currentWeekDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
 trailingSpaces = currentWeekDay;

 Log.d(tag, "Week Day:" + currentWeekDay + " is "
 + getWeekDayAsString(currentWeekDay));
 Log.d(tag, "No. Trailing space to Add: " + trailingSpaces);
 Log.d(tag, "No. of Days in Previous Month: " + daysInPrevMonth);

  if (cal.isLeapYear(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)))
 if (mm == 2)
  ++daysInMonth;
 else if (mm == 3)
  ++daysInPrevMonth;

 // Trailing Month days
   for (int i = 0; i < trailingSpaces; i++) {
  Log.d(tag,
    "PREV MONTH:= "
    + prevMonth
    + " => "
    + getMonthAsString(prevMonth)
    + " "
    + String.valueOf((daysInPrevMonth
      - trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET)
      + i));
  list.add(String
  .valueOf((daysInPrevMonth - trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET)
     + i)
  + "-GREY"
     + "-"
  + getMonthAsString(prevMonth)
   + "-"
   + prevYear);
 }

  // Current Month Days
 for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
  Log.d(currentMonthName, String.valueOf(i) + " "
   + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + " " + yy);
  if (i == getCurrentDayOfMonth()) {
  list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-BLUE" + "-"
   + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
  } else {
  list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-"
   + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
 }
 }

 // Leading Month days
 for (int i = 0; i < list.size() % 7; i++) {
 Log.d(tag, "NEXT MONTH:= " + getMonthAsString(nextMonth));
 list.add(String.valueOf(i + 1) + "-GREY" + "-"
   + getMonthAsString(nextMonth) + "-" + nextYear);
}
 }

 /**
 * NOTE: YOU NEED TO IMPLEMENT THIS PART Given the YEAR, MONTH, retrieve
 * ALL entries from a SQLite database for that month. Iterate over the
 * List of All entries, and get the dateCreated, which is converted into
* day.
  * 
 * @param year
* @param month
  * @return
 */
 private HashMap<String, Integer> findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(int year,
 int month) {
 HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

 return map;
 }

@Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
 return position;
 }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 View row = convertView;
 if (row == null) {
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context
   .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_gridcell, parent, false);
}

 // Get a reference to the Day gridcell
 gridcell = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.calendar_day_gridcell);
 gridcell.setOnClickListener(this);

 // ACCOUNT FOR SPACING

  Log.d(tag, "Current Day: " + getCurrentDayOfMonth());
 String[] day_color = list.get(position).split("-");
  String theday = day_color[0];
  String themonth = day_color[2];
  String theyear = day_color[3];
  if ((!eventsPerMonthMap.isEmpty()) && (eventsPerMonthMap != null)) {
  if (eventsPerMonthMap.containsKey(theday)) {
  num_events_per_day = (TextView) row
   .findViewById(R.id.num_events_per_day);
 Integer numEvents = (Integer) eventsPerMonthMap.get(theday);
  num_events_per_day.setText(numEvents.toString());
 }
  }

 // Set the Day GridCell
 gridcell.setText(theday);
 gridcell.setTag(theday + "-" + themonth + "-" + theyear);
  Log.d(tag, "Setting GridCell " + theday + "-" + themonth + "-"
  + theyear);

 if (day_color[1].equals("GREY")) {
 gridcell.setTextColor(getResources()
   .getColor(R.color.lightgray));
 }
 if (day_color[1].equals("WHITE")) {
 gridcell.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
  R.color.lightgray02));
 }
 if (day_color[1].equals("BLUE")) {
   gridcell.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orrange));
 }
  return row;
 }

 @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
String date_month_year = (String) view.getTag();
selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText("Selected: " + date_month_year);
Log.e("Selected date", date_month_year);
try {
Date parsedDate = dateFormatter.parse(date_month_year);
 Log.d(tag, "Parsed Date: " + parsedDate.toString());

 } catch (ParseException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
  }
  }

  public int getCurrentDayOfMonth() {
   return currentDayOfMonth;
  }

  private void setCurrentDayOfMonth(int currentDayOfMonth) {
  this.currentDayOfMonth = currentDayOfMonth;
 }

 public void setCurrentWeekDay(int currentWeekDay) {
 this.currentWeekDay = currentWeekDay;
 }

 public int getCurrentWeekDay() {
  return currentWeekDay;
}
}
```

Comment: Could you trim your code to show only the relevant part please?

Comment: see uper part ofmy code is relevent code

Comment: see this code     // Current Month Days

Comment: Sun Mon Tues  Wednes Thurs Fri sat
   21  22   23    24     25    26  27

Comment: seemy last post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766665/how-to-get-current-week-days-in-calender

Comment: how i wil get  current week of dates